# Why does redis need write permissions for redis.conf?

Tags: linux, permissions, redis

I just installed redis on an Ubuntu server. When I examined its file permissions, I saw

`-rw-r----- 1 redis redis 59124 Jan 11 02:24 /etc/redis/redis.conf`

1. Why does the redis user need write access to the conf file?
2. Would it be more secure to change the permissions to `-r--r-----`? If so, what are the downsides (if any) to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but I expect this is because the command [CONFIG REWRITE](https://redis.io/commands/config-rewrite) was introduced in Redis 2.8.0 which rewrites the redis.conf file to match the currently configured process.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like even more reason to do `rename-command CONFIG ""`

Comment: I would recommend renaming it to a guid only you (or other redis admins) know, since being able to change config values without restarting the server is very valuable when making a highly-available service.